# How to show rows that only contain N/A values in R?

Tags: r, na

I am having trouble writing a formula in R that allows me to output only rows that contain "N/A". I assuming filter_all would be included since this would be applied to all of the columns in the dataset but please let me know!

Comment: You might want to try `df[!complete.cases(df),]` (where `df` is the name of your own data frame)

Answer (score 3):

`filter_all` is deprecated.  We can use `filter` with `if_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    filter(if_all(everything(), is.na))
```

---

If we are using the `penguins` dataset, not all columns have `NA`s

```
library(palmerpenguins)
data(penguins)
> colSums(is.na(penguins))
          species            island    bill_length_mm     bill_depth_mm flipper_length_mm       body_mass_g               sex 
                0                 0                 2                 2                 2                 2                11 
             year 
                0
```

i.e. 'species', 'island', 'year' have 0 NAs, so the above code with `if_all` returns 0 rows as a single row doesn't have all NA for all the columns.  We may need `if_any`

```
penguins %>%
    filter(if_any(everything(), is.na))
# A tibble: 11 × 8
   species island    bill_length_mm bill_depth_mm flipper_length_mm body_mass_g sex    year
   <fct>   <fct>              <dbl>         <dbl>             <int>       <int> <fct> <int>
 1 Adelie  Torgersen           NA            NA                  NA          NA <NA>   2007
 2 Adelie  Torgersen           34.1          18.1               193        3475 <NA>   2007
 3 Adelie  Torgersen           42            20.2               190        4250 <NA>   2007
 4 Adelie  Torgersen           37.8          17.1               186        3300 <NA>   2007
 5 Adelie  Torgersen           37.8          17.3               180        3700 <NA>   2007
 6 Adelie  Dream               37.5          18.9               179        2975 <NA>   2007
 7 Gentoo  Biscoe              44.5          14.3               216        4100 <NA>   2007
 8 Gentoo  Biscoe              46.2          14.4               214        4650 <NA>   2008
 9 Gentoo  Biscoe              47.3          13.8               216        4725 <NA>   2009
10 Gentoo  Biscoe              44.5          15.7               217        4875 <NA>   2009
11 Gentoo  Biscoe              NA            NA                  NA          NA <NA>   2009
```

Or if we want to check columns where there are at least one NA and returns the rows where they are all `NA`

```
penguins %>%
    filter(if_all(where(~ any(is.na(.x))), is.na))
# A tibble: 2 × 8
  species island    bill_length_mm bill_depth_mm flipper_length_mm body_mass_g sex    year
  <fct>   <fct>              <dbl>         <dbl>             <int>       <int> <fct> <int>
1 Adelie  Torgersen             NA            NA                NA          NA <NA>   2007
2 Gentoo  Biscoe                NA            NA                NA          NA <NA>   2009
```

Comment: Hello akrun, for some reason it did not work. I am working on the palmerpenguins dataset and tried applying your code but it read the following:

Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: @DXME have you loaded the `library(dplyr)` and also check the package version i.e.  I use `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.8’`

Comment: @DXME I updated with the output I get for the `penguins` data

Comment: Yes, I assume so because I downloaded tidyverse which should contain dplyr as well.

Comment: @DXME yes, it is there, but have you loaded the package `library(dplyr)`.  What I meant is that you may have the packages installed, but it may not be available in the session unless you load the package or use `dplyr::filter`